# 4750 Permission on a public_html

Tags: unix, permissions

Noticed that a public_html got a 4750 permission, instead of the classical 0750. 
I try changing the owner, or the permissions but whatever I do, it remains 4750. Anyone has an idea how to change the permission on a folder that got stuck on 4750?!

```
stat public_html
  File: `public_html'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 106692622   Links: 11
Access: (4750/drwsr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-08-22 20:00:51.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-08-22 19:48:45.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-08-22 20:06:05.000000000 +0200

chown newuser.nobody public_html
root@hx [/home/somedir]# stat public_html
  File: `public_html'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 106692622   Links: 11
Access: (4750/drwsr-x---)  Uid: (  934/newuser)   Gid: (   99/  nobody)
Access: 2016-08-22 20:00:51.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-08-22 19:48:45.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-08-22 20:06:22.000000000 +0200
root@hx [/home/somedir]# chmod 0750 public_html
root@hx [/home/somedir]# stat public_html
  File: `public_html'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 106692622   Links: 11
Access: (4750/drwsr-x---)  Uid: (  934/newuser)   Gid: (   99/  nobody)
Access: 2016-08-22 20:00:51.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-08-22 19:48:45.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-08-22 20:08:59.000000000 +0200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to clear the setuid bit with

```
chmod u-s public_html
```

From [`man chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod):

> **chmod** preserves a directory's set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits unless you explicitly specify otherwise. You can set or clear the bits with symbolic modes like **u+s** and **g-s**, and you can set (but not clear) the bits with a numeric mode.